# How enable inbuilt graphic card in 12.04?

Tags: graphics

I have a 12 year old P4 Desktop with 1 GB RAM and 128 MB on Chip Graphics.
Recently I have shifted form Windows to UBUNTU, so I am a beginner in Ubuntu.

Upon the suggestions made, I have put the following command in the terminal:-

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Which gave the following output :-

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device (rev 03)
```

This graphic card is present right from the time I have purchased the Desktop. I have not added any other graphic cards or any other peripherals.

Please suggest what to do further.

Comment: lspci | grep VGA output please .

Comment: Just to clear command is: `lspci | grep VGA` Edit your post to include the output.

Comment: do you have a discrete graphics card as well?

Comment: No Discrete Graphics Card.

Comment: Ubuntu uses the internal graphics card automatically.Don't need to worry.

Comment: Is there any specific problem with the graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses the internal graphics card automatically. Don't need to worry.